# Remove checkboxes from JTable in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have created one JTable with checkboxes in my project. Its fine. But the problem is how to remove the limited checkboxes based on index from that JTable. Can anyone tell me how to remove the limited checkboxes based on index from the JTable.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by the word "limited" in this context, perhaps by providing an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

```
JTable table = new JTable();
...
int row = ...
int column = ...
table.setValueAt("", row, column);
```

That will set whatever cell to contain an empty string rather than a checkbox. This also assumes you are just using the DefaultTableModel. If you are doing something different you will have to post some code snippets for anyone to properly answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have a JTable which you want to modify dynamically the best approach is to do that only by using a model. Make a class that extends [AbstractTableModel](http://j7a.ru/classjavax_1_1swing_1_1table_1_1_abstract_table_model.html), and use the `setValueAt` method in conjunction with `fireTableCellUpdated` in order to do your updates.

Read the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and if you still face problems return here for more clarifications.